# In C language fscanf reads last number twice

Tags: c

I have written this code to read from an input file and display the numbers:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i;
    FILE * f;
    f=fopen("inputA.txt","r");

    while (!feof(f)){
        fscanf(f, "%i", &i);
        printf("%i\t", i);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

The output shows the last number twice. I guess it is the problem of `feof` but I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
while( !feof(x) )
```

is incorrect.

You have to check the return value of fscanf() and only printf the `i` if the call was successful. If the fscanf() return value indicates an error, *then* you check feof() and break from the loop.